# LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to find header lambda-runtime-aws-request-id in response. Random errors when calling AWS Lambda from Spring Boot

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Spring Boot application from which I call my AWS Lambda function via Feign Client and AWS API Gateway. There are similar AWS Lambda functions with the exact configurations but I never seemed to have this problem.

When I call this lambda function the event is correct, lambda handles this event correctly and produces the right JSON in the end. Sometimes, it starts another event immediately after instead of returning the correct JSON (which was handled by the lambda) to Spring Boot and this second event starts and fails:

[image: cloudwatch logs]
[image: cloudwatch logs pt 2]

I have zero idea about why this happens. This situation doesn't happen all the time but it seems to be happening at exactly %50 of requests to this lambda. One request succeeds and then the other one fails. Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error was happening because I had the need to get local month names and for this I was setting the locale like:

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.UTF-8')

at some part of my code. The recommended way to set Locale for a AWS Lambda is through LANG variable in environment variables as in official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html).